# Jquery toggle for div with unique id

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, foreach

I have to display each products from database that client ordered, but I want to show/hide them on a div click.
http://prntscr.com/7c5q6t

This is my php code where i display all ordered products.

```
<td class="left">
 <?php 
   foreach ($order['OrderedProducts'] as $OrderedProduct) {
    echo "<div class='toggle' id=$OrderedProduct[order_product_id]>Show/hide</div>"."<br>";
    echo "Product id:". $OrderedProduct[order_product_id]."<br>".$OrderedProduct[name]."<br>";
} ?>
</td>
```

Please help me with some jquery to toggle the div by unique ordered products id.

Comment: Pls show us your generated HTML code.

Comment: If you're using jQuery UI I'd suggest looking at https://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Answer (score 0):

Find the below code,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(div.toggle).click(function(){
      $(this).next().toggle('hide');
   });
});

<td class="left">
   <?php 
      foreach ($order['OrderedProducts'] as $OrderedProduct) {
      echo "<div class='toggle' id=$OrderedProduct[order_product_id]>Show/hide</div>"."<br>";
      echo "<div>Product id:". $OrderedProduct[order_product_id]."<br>".$OrderedProduct[name]."</div><br>";
      }
   ?>
</td>
```

Comment: Jquery [slidetoggle](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/) is nice aswell, but good answer!

Comment: @Naruto : Thanks. Sure slidetoggle will look nice.

Answer (score -1):

You can wrap product info into the div and use jQuery method [.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) and some CSS to hide/show this div

Javascript:

```
$('.toggle').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('hide');
});
```

CSS:

```
.toggle.hide + div {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Add an onclick to your div:

```
<td class="left">
 <?php 
   foreach ($order['OrderedProducts'] as $OrderedProduct) {
    echo "<div onclick='showHide(this)' class='toggle' id=$OrderedProduct[order_product_id]>Show/hide</div>"."<br>";
    echo "Product id:". $OrderedProduct[order_product_id]."<br>".$OrderedProduct[name]."<br>";
} ?>
</td>
```

Then put this little puppy in a script tag to show or hide it:

```
window.showHide = function(dom) {
    var hidden = $(dom).css('display') != 'none';
    if (hidden)
    {
        $(dom).show();
    }
    else
    {
        $(dom).hide();
    }
};
```

Comment: Never use inline event handlers when you're using jQuery!

Answer (score -1):

This is simple way to toggle.

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).on("click", ".toggle", function() { 
      if ($(this).css("display") === "none") {
          $(this).show()
      } else {
          $(this).hide()
      }
})
```

**EDIT**

```
$(document).on("click", ".toggle", function() { 
      $(this).toggle()
})
```